# $a_n>0$ for all $n\in N$ does not imply that the limit point $a_{\infty}>0$?

Tags: limits

I think it is correct that $a_n>0$ for all $n\in N$ does not implies the limit point $a_{\infty}>0$.

This is because $+\infty$ is not an element of natural numbers and we let $a_n=1/n$ as a counterexample.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\infty$ is not a natural number is irrelevant here. Your example works indeed, and therefore the statement is false. But what your example shows is that if $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers greater than $0$ and if you denote its limit by $a_\infty$, then you don't necessarily have $a_\infty=0$.

If, for instance, the statement that you were working with was

> If $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers greater than or equal to $0$ and if you denote its limit by $a_\infty$, then $a_\infty\geqslant0$.

then the statement would be correct, in spite of the fact that $\infty\notin\Bbb N$.